# Query for list of files and folders in root directory

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to get a list of files and folders in the root directory without having to sort through all the files.  Is there a query that would do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The root folder can also be addressed with a special alias named "root", so you can get all files and folders in the root with the following query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root' in parents
```

Remember to escape the URL if not using one of the client libraries (they automatically take care of it).

For more details about the search query language, check https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: Thanks works like a charm! But I found a few files that seem to not have any parent, they don't come up in the root query or any other folder query.  Is that possible? Bug?

Comment: That's a great one Claudio! Did I miss this in the documentation?

Comment: i am using the service account with the php library. how to i access all files and folders?

Comment: You can use domain-wide delegation to access other domain users' documents: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: so thanks i'am looking for than almost two hours there is no any document for explain this

Comment: escape like this \'root\' in parents" c#

Comment: is there a way to search in multiple folders? not only root.

Answer (score 6):

This code will display all files and folder of your **ROOT DIRECTORY**. just copy and paste this code and you will get all your root's file and folder.

```
 List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = null;

    try {
          request = mService.files().list();
          FileList files = request.setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false").execute();
          result.addAll(files.getItems());          
          request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }

 //Print out all the files and folder of root Directory  
  for(File f:result)
  {
      System.out.println("recvd data are: "+f.getTitle());
  }
```

Comment: you might want to add trashed=false to prevent deleted files showing up

Comment: @pinoyyid thanks for your suggestion. I have updated it. You can see it here now.

Comment: I just tested, it only print files not the folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Google drive v3** [Reference the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) helps to create DriveClient object.

Run this below method in the background thread(Android).

Note: Required Scope permission "DriveScopes.DRIVE"

```
 protected String[] getListChildren(String parentId) throws Exception {
    String[] children = null;
   parentId = parentId == null ? "root" : parentId;
    String fileQuery = "'" + parentId + "' in parents and trashed=false";
    FileList files = driveService.files().list().setQ(fileQuery).execute();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File file : files.getFiles()) {
        fileNames.add(file.getName());
    }
    children = fileNames.toArray(new String[0]);
    return children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query for a **Shared Drive** should be `"'driveId' in parents`.

Using `'root'` works for **My Drive** only.